# Get File Path With File Name in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Suppose I have the file **abc.txt** within a subdirectory of every users' *Music folder*.

I want to replace that **abc.txt** for each user using batch with "**c:\users\abc.txt**".

I have command for copy that can be used in loop,

**xcopy  /s/z “source pfile path” “destination path”**

But how to get list of File Paths?

Comment: Are you asking about a list of *paths* or a list of **users**?
I would have thought the path would always just be `C:\Users\<username>\Music\abc.txt`?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: C:\Users\<username>\<any random folder>\abc.txt

Comment: I think you need to edit your question in that case.  The way it reads now, the *Music folder* is mentioned twice, when seemingly it is irrelevant? If the file you seek can truly be in "any random folder".

Comment: As far as I understand you have the following folder structure: "C:\Users\Jon\Music", "C:\Users\Henry\Music", "C:\Users\Annette\Music" and so on. Right?

Comment: @shaggy007 Are you maybe just looking for a way to find a file anywhere on the computer? Or are you looking for a way to get the username in a variable (which would be `%username%`)? You should try to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "skip=2 tokens=4" %A in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "My Music"') do set Doc=%A
```

Sets doc to current user's My Music folder.

You would do this as a logon script else you won't be allowed access to other user's My Music.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question?  This piece of code just sets a variable to the *My Music* folder location of each user?
Also, why would this be done in a logon script!?  The OP wanted a [batch-file]

Comment: As [@shaggy007](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5881576/shaggy007) said in his comment; "any random folder".  I don't see what a logon script to find the My Music folder has to do with finding *any* folder under the user profile that contains a specific text file?

Comment: He wants the music folder. He wants to copy a file into it. He knows that command. I tell him how to find the music folder. _every user's Music folder_